# How can I get make cookies work without webserver?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, cookies

I have made some cookies using JavaScript. The code works but I understand that they need to be run using HTTP or some other protocol. The most obvious answer would be run the website using a webserver but that seems like a bad option for me as I am on a school network with restrictions and I need to make my website distributable so that I can send it to the exam board.

Background: the website is made-up of notepad documents, converted to html documents. So open them with browser and the webpage is displayed. But the cookies don't run properly so I need a way to make the cookies work without a webserver if possible.

I was thinking maybe there is a piece of development software that lets you view your website using protocols. It would be great if there was a piece of software that lets you compile your website into something small and distributable but with inbuilt HTTP or something. I don't know. Maybe Visual Studio has something?

Comment: You can distribute Apache/Nginx with your app if required, but it's not a pretty thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use cookies without HTTP, because cookies are an HTTP mechanism.

Instead of cookies, you could use [`localStorage`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/), which works even with files loaded from `file://` URLs (e.g., without a web server) (except on IE — quelle shock!). `localStorage` is also dramatically easier to use from JavaScript than cookies:

```
// Save a string in local storage
localStorage.setItem("foo", theString);

// Get it (perhaps on page load)
var theString = localStorage.getItem("foo");
```